# VBA: Sort with blank / no / empty value in first position / at beginning. Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I want to sort a range of columns alphabetically by the Value in f3 (3, 6). Sometimes it will happen that my data has no value in this f3 (3, 6). I've read that this will often cause errors. In my case I get an error the first time I execute the code, but the second time it works fine. What could be the issue?

The second example of code is part of the same macro, is almost identical, sorts the rows, and works the first time the code is executed.

```
Worksheets(FileName).Range(Worksheets(FileName).Cells(1, 6), _
Cells(Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Rows.Count, _
Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Sort Key1:=Worksheets(FileName).Range(Cells(3, 6), _
Cells(3, anzahlDerKurse)), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight 'Sortiert Kurse alphabetisch


Worksheets(FileName).Range(Worksheets(FileName).Cells(9, 1), _
    Cells(Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Rows.Count, _
    Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Sort Key1:=Worksheets(FileName).Range(Cells(9, 3), _
    Cells(Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3)), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom 'Sortiert User nach last active
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(FileName).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(FileName).Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
    :=Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(3, Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Columns.Count)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(FileName).Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Rows.Count, Worksheets(FileName).UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .Apply
End With
```

Was the solution. I don't know the exact mistake I've made, but this seems to work. Sometimes it's wise to use the macro recorder.